# Fifo page replacement infinite loop issue

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop, page-replacement

I am trying to do page replacement algorithm in C. I wrote the code below. I have written similar code that had worked below. But now when I try to reproduce the code enters an infinite loop.

I checked the for loop for hit and miss and it becomes stationary while current increments are unlimited. I have been tweaking the program for some time but nothing seems to work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int n,table[20],fsize,i,j,request[20],arr2[20],current,miss;

void initialize(int arr[],int n){ //set frame entries to -1
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr[i]=-1;
    }
}

int isavailable(int arg){ //checks if entry is available in frame table (array)
    int present=0;
    for(i=0;i<fsize;i++){
        if(table[i]==arg){
            present=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return present;
}

void fifo(){ //first in first out
    miss=0;
    current=-1;
    initialize(table,fsize);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        arr2[i]=request[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(isavailable(arr2[i])==1){ //hit condition
                printf("Hit");
                continue;
            }
            current=(current+1)%fsize; //interates in a cycle during miss
            table[current]=arr2[i]; //places in first entered location
            miss++;
    }
    printf("Total misses: %d",miss);
}

void main(){
    printf("Enter number of requests: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter table size: "); //reads frame table size
    scanf("%d",&fsize);
    printf("Enter requests: ");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&request[i]); //reads request sequence in array
    }
    printf("FIFO: ");
    fifo();
    printf("LRU: ");
    //lru();
    printf("Optimal: ");
    //optimal();
    
}
```

Edit:-
The input i gave are:-

- no of requests: 7
- sizeoftable: 3
- request: 1,3,0,3,5,6,3

Comment: OT: Why all the global variables? You do know about function arguments, *use them*. And what happens if `n >= 20`?

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values?

Comment: Regarding the global variables, just because you use the same names in multiple functions doesn't mean they need to be global. Case in point: The variable `i`... You use it in many loops in different functions. It shouldn't be a global variable, it should be a loop-local variable. Like `for (int i = 0; i < fsize; ++i)` (for example).

Comment: [Edit] and show an example of input that triggers the problem.

Comment: ***Always*** check what `scanf` [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value).

Answer (score 1):

An input of

```
1,3,0,3,5,6,3
```

will cause `scanf("%d",&request[i]);` to *fail* on the second iteration when it reads an invalid character of `,`. This character will be left in the input buffer, and will cause subsequent iterations to also fail.

Only the first element of `request` is given a user-submitted value, the rest remain zero-initialized (due to static allocation).

You must check the return value of `scanf` is the expected number of *conversions*. Here we want to convert *one* integer (`%d`), so we check for a return value of `1` (or the inverse to check for error).

```
if (1 != scanf("%d", &request[i])) {
   /* Handle this problem.
    * A basic way:
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input!\n");
    exit(1);
    */
}
```

`%d` skips leading whitespace, so the input

```
1 3 0 3 5 6 3
```

is more appropriate for the specifier.

---

Using the global variable `i` as a for the loop condition in both `fifo` **and** the *nested* call to `isavailable` causes the value to ping-pong between `1` and `0` (with the given input), thus never reaching `n`.

The solution is to use more locally scoped variables, so that functions do not interfere with each other.

Here is a refactored example.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ALLOC 32

static void panic(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static int contains(int *array, size_t length, int value)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if (value == array[i])
            return 1;

    return 0;
}

static size_t fifo(size_t tsize, const int *requests, size_t rsize)
{
    int pages[tsize];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < tsize; i++)
        pages[i] = -1;

    size_t miss = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0, offset = 0; i < rsize; i++) {
        if (contains(pages, tsize, requests[i]))
            continue;

        pages[offset++ % tsize] = requests[i];
        miss++;
    }

    return miss;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t rsize = 0;
    size_t tsize = 0;

    printf("Enter number of requests: ");
    if (1 != scanf("%zu", &rsize))
        panic("Invalid `rsize` format.\n");

    printf("Enter table size: ");
    if (1 != scanf("%zu", &tsize))
        panic("Invalid `tsize` format.\n");

    if (!rsize || rsize > MAX_ALLOC || !tsize || tsize > MAX_ALLOC)
        panic("Bad size(s) (`rsize`: %zu) (`tsize`: %zu) [1, %d]\n",
                rsize, tsize, MAX_ALLOC);

    int requests[rsize];

    printf("Enter requests: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rsize; i++)
        if (1 != scanf("%d", &requests[i]))
            panic("Invalid `request` (%zu)", i + 1);

    printf("FIFO: %zu misses\n", fifo(tsize, requests, rsize));
}
```

```
Enter number of requests: 7  
Enter table size: 3
Enter requests: 1 3 0 3 5 6 3
FIFO: 6 misses
```

Comment: I didn't use `,` in the input. I just wrote that to signify those numbers are my input. I input the letters one by one each seperated by enter key.

Comment: Well, the advice about checking the return value of `scanf` is just as important, regardless, but you should have clarified the format in your question, otherwise it is assumed that the example data is literal. The global `i` remains the reason for the infinite loop. Does making `i` local to each function (or loop) solve your problem?